# Gerrit ref-update hook is not getting invoked

Tags: gerrit

Installed Gerrit (version 2.13.1) by following the steps in the following link:
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install-quick.html
in Ubuntu 16.04 environment.

Created a hooks folder in '$site_path'/hooks and added a ref-update hook file which just exits with return code 1.

Provided executable permissions to this file.

After Gerrit server restart, it is allowing me to do a push operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Gerrit 2.13 you have to install the hooks plugin.

See more details at [Gerrit 2.13 Release Notes](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.13.md#Hooks-Plugin) and [Gerrit Documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html).

The hooks plugin is a core plugin, it is packaged within the Gerrit war file and can be installed executing:

```
java -jar gerrit.war init -d <site_path> --install-plugin=hooks
```

More info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#core-plugins).

Comment: Can we download hooks plugin jar directly?

Comment: I updated the answer with the hooks plugin install info.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Gerrit 2.14. This works for me:

Behavior change in ref-update hook

Instead of being invoked on every commit received, the ref-update hook is now invoked before the ref update operation is finalized. The previous behavior of the ref-update hook is moved into a new hook named commit-received.

**Sites using the ref-update hook should rename the hook file to commit-received.**

https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.14.md#Behavior-change-in-ref_update-hook

Answer (score 0):

You can also add hooks manually:

1. Create folder for example /hooks
2. Add in this folder file ref-update
3. Make this file executable using this command `chmod +x ref-update`
4. Last things is add text below to **gerrit.config** file, my file is in /var/gerrit/review_site/etc/ but please check where yours file is

This you need add to your **gerrit.config** file:

```
[hooks]
     path = /hooks
```

In generally way:

```
[hooks]
     path = /path/to/yours/hooks/folder/hooks
```

Comment: These steps are not working for Gerrit 2.13.1. They used to work for some previous versions.

Comment: Ou, sorry I have 2.12.3 version.. my bad.